# GoF's implementation of the Prototype pattern

Tags: c++, design-patterns, prototype-pattern

(This question is more for the people who have access to the book, It's hard to put it into context otherwise)

I've been reading through the GoF's *'Design Patterns'* book and there's a sentence that confuses me a little, under  *'Creational Patterns->Prototype->Sample code'*  (page 124).

Near the bottom of the page, there is the implemententation for `BombedWall`, which as I understand is a concrete prototype, as it inherits from `Wall`, and redefines the `Clone()` virtual function. `BombedWall` also defines *another* method, `HasBomb()`, unknown to any clients using the regular `Wall` interface.

The only way that `BombedWall` is stored in `MazePrototypeFactory` (the Prototype client) is as a `Wall*` (returned from `BombedWall::Clone`), and the only way to get to `HasBomb()` afterwards, as far as I understand, is to perform a downcast on that `Wall*` to a `BombedWall*` (dynamic or static, depending on whether I know the type), and then I can access the `HasBomb()` method.

This all seemed fine to me; but then *later* the author says (same page, last sentence, 2nd last paragraph):

> "Clients should never have to downcast the return value of `Clone` to
>   the desired type"

What? Then how am I supposed to get to `HasBomb()`?

I must be missing something...

Comment: [Here](http://www.nileshgule.com/2012/06/prototype-design-pattern.html) is an implementation of Prototype Design Pattern using Interface. Even without subclassing, we can create an instance by using a prototype object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I gave an answer and totally rewrote it now :)

Basically, the MazePrototypeFactory only knows about the base classes it can use. It doesn't know anything about any of the subclasses you are going to make, but it still should be able to put any possible subclass out there into the maze.

The pattern basically ensures MazeFactory will get a pointer of a type that it understands, Wall, than cause the MazeFactory to need to be modified to be able to produce objects of all the subclasses.

MazeFactory is the client referred to on p 124. It doesn't need to know about HasBomb in order to build the maze.

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that this method only exists to indicate that `BombedWall` is a different class with extended public interface. Hovewer, this interface is not used in the context of the sample: the maze building algorithm does not differentiate types of walls, while other subsystems (for example, rendering engine) may do so.